# unresolvable-dependency-resolving-at-component-class

Tags: php, laravel, components

I have a component that loads inputs
Editable.php

```php
<?php
namespace App\View\Components;
use Illuminate\View\Component;
class Editable extends Component
{
    public $type;
    public $name;
    public $value;
    public $pk;
    public $model;
    public $mode;
    public $url;
    public $numberformat;
    public $decimal;
    public $source;
    public $title;
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($type, $name, $value, $pk, $model, $mode = "inline", $url = '', $numberformat = 0, $decimal = 0, $source = '', $title = '')
    {
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->pk = $pk;
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->mode = $mode;
        $this->url = ($url) ? $url : route("admin.common.changeEntity");
        $this->numberformat = (int) $numberformat;
        $this->decimal = (int) $decimal;
        $this->source = $source;
        $this->title = $title;
    }
    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.editable');
    }
}
```

And I use the component like this:

```html
   @forelse($currencies as $item)
     <x-Editable type="text" name="buy" :value="$item->buy" :pk="$item->id" model="Currency" numberformat="1" title="edit currency" />
   @empty
  @endforelse
```

at my localhost everything is fine but at the server, I get this error

```php
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #5 [ <optional> $mode ]] in class App\View\Components\Editable (View: /home/***/resources/views/admin/default/currencies/index.blade.php)
```

PHP version at localhost is  7.4.16 and PHP version at the server is  7.4.16 too